# How could I have improved this post?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, unanswered-questions

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [How does cloudflare detect that I am a bot even though I have provided the cf_clearance cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75857794/how-does-cloudflare-detect-that-i-am-a-bot-even-though-i-have-provided-the-cf-cl)

I posted it two days ago, it has 30 views with no votes or answers—except the guy who told me to run his reverse shell; how can I improve my post? I have followed the [how to ask a good question page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), but I do not see what I did wrong. Was it too trivial to the community?

Comment: Not getting any answers or comments doesn't necessarily mean you've done anything wrong or there's anything to improve. It could just mean that the people who viewed it don't know the answer.

Comment: There is no requirement that your question gets an answer; the site don't provide SLAs because everyone here is a volunteer. Some questions *don't* get answered even if they are good. There are 100's of questions posted on [so] *every* day; far too many for the volunteers to view and answer all of them. The normal method for such a scenario is to place a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on the question, to have the question "promoted" and offer reputation as an incentive to answer. This, however, means you need to earn yourself some reputation first.

Comment: Understood. Looks like someone has already placed a bounty and upvoted it, presumably from this question. Thank you to whoever it was!

Comment: I would just add that your question is the latest in a _very_ long arms race between companies like Cloudflare and various script writers.  If someone does know the answer today, they may be reluctant to publish it least Cloudflare updates their side and makes it even harder tomorrow instead of a few days from now.

Comment: Can anyone not working at cloud flare answer the question at all?

Comment: @AnonCoward I see, I also thought about this, so I am not looking for a cannonical question, rather a general brief of how cloudflare might do this. Inputting the _puid cookie for chatgpt (which also uses cloudflare) completely bypasses cloudflare, so not sure why cf_clearance does not do the same

Comment: In the future, please flag anyone trying to get you to run blatant malware for moderator attention.  We will happily remove their ability to continue doing that.

Comment: "rather a general brief of how cloudflare might do this"  Honestly, I hope you get an answer, just be aware the answer might be some variant of "a giant ever changing black box of heuristics and checks that no single human anywhere completely understands"

Comment: [/help/no-one-answers](/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: It's not clear to me how the question could be properly answered, except by speculation that happens to turn out correct, unless we have actual Cloudflare engineers looming around. There are perhaps a few different sensible things that a website *could* try, but that's different from knowing what a *specific* site *does* try.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think that this question needs to be improved - in general, it has what the community look for in a question. Looking at [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask):

> Make sure your question is on-topic and suitable for this site.

Your question is about accessing a website with Python, both of which are topics that are common on this site, and your question as a whole covers a suitable issue that you have tried to fix. That brings me to the second part:

> Help others reproduce the problem.

You have also done that and provided a good Minimal Reproducable Example. It appears [Aarav Prasad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15326565/aarav-prasad) has offered a bounty on your question, which will encourage other users to answer it (because if their answer meets [The Bounty Criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), they will recieve a reputation bonus). Overall, your question seems to be good and I can't see any large ways it could be improved.